# DataGridView CurrentCellChanged event doesn't let me select more than one row

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, multi-select

I have a DataGridView on my form. I set CurrentCellChanged event for it, MultiSelect property is true but now I can't select more than one row!

I want to be able to select more than 1 row.

Comment: show the code under `CurrentCellChanged` event

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is - please explain clearly what you are expecting to see and what you are seeing. Also please provide the minimum complete code needed to reproduce the problem. MultiSelect select works  when the CurrentCellChanged event is handled so you must be doing something to cause the problem.

Comment: I added Some Code to Calculate the Statistical information about all other Rows. I Use dataGridView1.SelectAll() to get access all the fields, that I think this Command don't let me to select other rows. how can I force the program to wait for my selection (use Ctrl or Shift key)

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Why do you need to call SelectAll() to be able to access the data in the grid? Of course if you select all when the current cell changes you won't be able to select particular cells. Explain what you are trying to do and show your current code.

Comment: Thank you dear David, I'm beginner in C#, and your comment help me to use other  method for my project. thank you so much. there was a better solution and you help me to find it.